# the proof or counter example: continuity of a multi-variable function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $f: D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by
$$
f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
x^\frac{1}{2}y^{-\frac{1}{4}}(1-y)^{\frac{1}{2}}-y^{-\frac{1}{4}}(x-y)^{\frac{1}{2}} ~&\hbox{for}~ (x,y) \in D\setminus \{(x,y) : y \neq 0\},\\
0~&\hbox{for}~ (x,y) \in D\cap  \{(x,y) : y = 0\},
\end{cases}
$$
where $D=\{ (x,y) : 0 \le y\le x \le 1\}$.  I was wondering if the function $f$ is continuous on D.

I tried to find some counterexample. Clearly, $f(x,x)=x^{\frac{1}{4}}(1-x)^{\frac{1}{2}} \to 0$ as $x \to 0$.
Similarly, $f(x,x^2)=(1-x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}-(1-x)^{\frac{1}{2}} \to 0$ as $x \to 0$. I could not find any counterexample in this way. Unfortunately, I have no idea to prove the continuity of the multi-valued function $f.$

Any comments on my question would be appreciated.

Comment: You should add some (even partial) attempt.

Comment: [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). In particular, this question lacks both the motivation and any attempts to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems fair to assume that the function stays continuous everywhere in domain except around $y = 0$.
To check continuity in this region, lets see if $$f(x,0) = \lim_{y \to 0}f(x,y)$$
taking the RHS,
\begin{align}\lim_{y \to 0} f(x,y) &= \lim_{y \to 0}\frac{x^\frac{1}{2}(1-y)-(x-y)^\frac{1}{2}}{y^\frac{1}{4}}\\
&= \lim_{y \to 0}\frac{x^\frac{1}{2}(1-\frac{1}{2}y+\frac{1}{8}y^2\cdots)-(x^\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}yx^\frac{-1}{2}\cdots)}{y^\frac{1}{4}}\\
&= 0 = f(x,0)
\end{align}
So it seems the function is indeed continuous in its domain
**Terms $(1-y)^\frac{1}{2}$ and $(x-y)^\frac{1}{2}$ are expanded using [binomial expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Generalizations)